# How to show ID column in Grails' scaffolded views?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails3

Is there any way to show the ID column in Grails 3 scaffolded views so as to allow editing it and specifying it manually when creating a new entry? By default, the column specified as `id` in domain class's mapping is invisible in the list view, `show` or `edit` or `create`. Sometimes, though, I need the ID to be visible there and to be able to manually change it. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it! So in order to specify the fields you want rendered in these views, you go to the respective `*.gps` file, say `edit.gsp` and a the bottom of the file, change the `<f:all bean="<name>"/>` to an explicit list of columns, like this:

```
                <f:with bean="<name>">
                    <f:field property="frequency"/>
                    <f:field property="unit"/>
                    <f:field property="description"/>
                    <f:field property="lang"/>
                </f:with>
```

... and it's done! The only exception is the `index` where the list is. In order to change that one, you edit the `index.gsp` to reflect specific properties in the `f:table collection` tag:

```
    <f:table collection="${aliasFrequencyDictList}" properties="['frequency','unit','description','lang']"/>
```

Comment: You can also do this: <f:table collection="${configList}" except="[]"/>